# How to modify makeindex script in VS code for Latex

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I am trying to create a list of nomenclature for a report in latex. I am writing it in Microsoft Visual Code. An extension called "Latex Workshop" is used to generate the PDF. However, it is does not include the list of nomenclature. In few resources available on the web, it says to modify the "makeindex" script. Is it possible to do the same using VS code?

Comment: The extension only *helps* you compile, it does not generate the PDF. And this is not even related to VS Code.

Comment: This is an extension from VS code and I am finding it difficult to modify its settings similar to "makescript" in Miktex.

Comment: If you installed a TeX distribution (TeX Live or MiKTeX) correctly, even if you uninstall the extension, you can still compile your document normally using the command line. No, as I see this has nothing to do with VS Code and LaTeX Workshop.

Comment: The sole use of LateX Workshop extension is to avoid the use of command line, for which VS code automatically compiles it using that extension while we just save the document. I was wondering if we can have settings changed for that extension. With Tex live editor I am able to get it done properly.

Comment: So what is your command then? If you already have the compilation command, you can add it to `settings.json` and it will work.

Comment: did you find the solution for vscode?

Comment: No, I have not yet found it. I tried in settings.json but I am not able to figure out.

Answer (score 6):

You must configure a recipe (and corresponding tools) in settings.json for Visual Studio Code. This is because the package nomecl for LaTeX has custom compiling rules that must be followed.

You can access settings.json under **Files->Preferences->Settings**

Then go to Extensions and click on **"Edit in settings.json"** wherever you can. You can find it under **LaTeX->LaTeX:Tools**, highlighted in blue.

Once there the recipes and tools for settings.json should go like this:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "pdflatex ➞ makeindex ➞ pdflatex`×2",
            "tools": [
              "pdflatex",
              "makeindex",
              "pdflatex",
              "pdflatex"
            ]
          }
]
```

and

```
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        { 
            "name": "makeindex",
            "command": "makeindex",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%.nlo",
                "-s",
                "nomencl.ist",
                "-o",
                "%DOCFILE%.nls"
            ]
        }
]
```

Following json conventions of course. Mind the comas. I'm omitting the recipes for pdflatex and others. I think those are already defined outside settings.json.

Once you have this, the **Build LaTeX project** options will show you a custom build recipe. Executing that your nomenclature will show up.

Comment: Sources:
[nomencl doc](http://cs.brown.edu/about/system/managed/latex/doc/nomencl.pdf)
[Issue on github discussing this problem](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/384)